# scramble https over http to avoid detection by Firewall

Tags: firewall, http, ssl, https, spoofing

My campus has recently installed **Fortigate Firewall** and have started spoofing https certs.
eg. Certificates appear to be invalid saying: **"Google.com; verified by Fortinet CA"**
Is there a way to scramble https traffic such that, it is invisible to Firewall and still equally secure.

Comment: You can use a VPN that would make it so only a single secure connection was't actually secure.

Comment: Is this only a problem when trying to access Google, or is it all HTTPS sites? Is it happening when accessing any SSL service, or just specifics (like IMAP mail)?  This wreaks of a misconfigured/malfunctioning MITM technique for sniffing SSL traffic by the Fortigate.  When you asked your campus IT why this was happening what did they say what the reason/solution was?

Comment: I think it was a glitch by tech team. Now, it is solved. However, i would still be interested in such a method. bdw, 'All' SSL connections were being affected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a man-in-the-middle attack, and your WWW browser told you that it was happening.  The man in the middle was your campus IT department.  It almost certainly hasn't been "solved" as such.  The man in the middle has simply taken advantage of xyr privileged position *as* the IT department to instruct your computer not to warn you about the interception of your SSL traffic any more.

A lot of enterprise-level firewalls do this nowadays.  It's known variously as "SSL Proxy", "SSL Inspection", "HTTPS Inspection", "HTTPS Content Inspection", and so forth.  The first is the most accurate, as this practice applies to more than just encrypted HTTP.  Firewalls apply it to other encrypted protocols as well, including encrypted SMTP, IMAP, POP, and FTP.

Simply put, the firewall is doing exactly what the encryption is designed to guard against: intercepting the mail, WWW, and FTP traffic between you and the world, decrypting it, reading and possibly altering it, and re-encrypting it.

In the normal case, as you saw, your WWW browser spots this and complains.

So what the people who run such firewalls do is force an extra *certificate authority* onto your machine, into your WWW browser's list of *trusted* certificate authorities.  Your WWW browser sees that the certificate used by the part of the firewall that faces you is signed by this trusted certificate authority that has been forced upon you, and believes that everything is alright.

Such forcing is done in corporate setups by deploying the additional trusted certificate authority via Group Policy, onto all of the corporate computers.

Where this is impractical, an alternative that can be employed is for the organization to buy a signing certificate authority from a trusted root certificate authority, and use that to sign all of the nonce certificates that are handed to your WWW browser by the firewall.  Again, your browser sees a proper chain of certificates leading back to one of the trusted root certificate authorities on its list, and believes that everything is alright.

In both cases, all of your WWW, mail, FTP, and other apparently secure traffic has in fact been seen, read, and possibly altered (if it decided that it didn't like the content for whatever reason) by your campus IT department, in such a way that to the inexpert eye, looking for the pretty "lock" icons in WWW browsers and their ilk, everything appears secure.

### Further reading

- [*Add a trusted root certification authority to a Group Policy object*](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc738131(v=ws.10).aspx).  2005-01-21.  TechNet.   Microsoft corporation.
- [*Tehnical Tip: How to enable deep content inspection*](http://kb.fortinet.com/kb/viewContent.do?externalId=FD30586).  2013-08-20.  Fortinet KnowledgeBase.  FD30586.
- [*Technical Note : Importing the FortiGate SSL Proxy certificate in Internet Explorer 8 (IE8) for decryption on SSL Inspection*](http://kb.fortinet.com/kb/viewContent.do?externalId=FD32404).  2011-12-21.  Fortinet KnowledgeBase.  FD32404.
- [*Planning for HTTPS inspection*](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ee658156.aspx).  2009-11-15.  TechNet.  Microsoft corporation.
- [*What Is HTTPS Content Inspection?*](http://www.ntsecurity.com/learn/https_content_inspection.html).  2012-07-12.  NT Security.
- [*How to use your own HTTPS Proxy CA certificate on the Astaro Security Gateway*](http://www.sophos.com/en-gb/support/knowledgebase/2450/2800/4550/115592.aspx).  2012-05-08.  Sophos KnowledgeBase.  115592.